# shortcodes - style them or change/remove the square brackets?

Tags: customization, shortcode

I sometimes use for the clients, plugins that are based on wordpress shortcodes,they  do offer a lot of options for the clients to play with like adding tabs galleries and so on.

But I see that the appearance of the shortcode itself is still a bit confusing to them.
so is there a way to customize them like instead of `[gallery]content here...[gallery/]`

it will be something like : `open gallery... end of gallery` and with out the square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am sure that this is theoritically possible, I am going to say "No, not really".

If you [look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L225),  you can see that those brackets are hard-coded into a very complicated regex.  I see no filters that will let you change that.

The only reasonable way to approach this that I can think of would be:

1. To remove the default shortcode system using
   `remove_filter('do_shortcode','the_content');`
2. Add your own shortcode system

This, of course, will break any plugin supplied shortcodes as well as the core ones. So the other option would be to:

1. Add your own "wrapper" that converts whatever pattern you want to
   use into standard shortcodes
2. And run `do_shortcode` on the result before returning the result

I *think* you should be able to preserve the functionality of Core and Plugin shortcodes as well as add your own pattern, but the regex you are needing is complex especially given the pattern you require.

Either option is far more code than I have time to address, not to mention the debugging that would be involved.

Comment: Note that _removing_ or _combining_ isn't actually necessary. Nothing prevents from letting core do native shortcodes and another callback doing "custom" shortcodes. Still overkill for my taste too, but not that crazy if really necessary.

Comment: @Rarst, yes, true. I was thinking about trying to _preserve_ the native shortcodes while also hiding them as the OP thinks his clients find the brackets confusing, so you'd have to combine them to get the native "gallery" functionality, for example.

Comment: ok I see ,can I select them and give them some color  ?like this ?         $('\\ [gallery]').css("color" , "red");